# SQL Server view Stored Procedures full relationships

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, relational-database, diagram

I am working on a bunch of very complicated stored procedures on SQLSERVER 2012 Express databases using SQLSEVER 2012 Management studio.

For example I have a stored procedure SP1 calling another stored procedure SP2 and SP2 calls SP3, SP3 calls SP4 ...

What I would like to see is a diagram that can provide me the full relationships between these stored procedures and all the tables that being used in these stored procedures.

I have tried the view dependencies tools provided by SQL Server management studio, but sometimes it misses descendants stored procedures when I click "View Dependencies" of a selected stored procedure. Also it can't show a full picture of relationships between these stored procedures.

Is there any tool can help me with this? Or any suggestions on how to understand complicated relationship stored procedures?

Comment: stored procs nesting like this is a nightmare to document. There really isn't a great tool for this because it involves recursion. You have to view the dependencies of each dependent object.

Comment: Did you try Redgate?

Comment: @SeanLange But view one by one takes too much time and I am new to this project, any experience on how to speed things up?

Comment: @mhan0125 I searched you need to pay for Redgate, it there any other tool that can help?

Comment: If you have your procedures in version control (or at least somewhere in disc) you could just write a script with your favourite language to find the dependencies, assuming you don't actually need a diagram

Comment: SQL search from RedGate is free. But you still have the problem of recursion. I feel your pain but you either have to search it manually or write up a recursive loop that looks through sys.depends

Comment: View Dependencies on a SQL Server 2012 database should not be missing any dependencies other than those from Dynamic SQL, which are intractable by any means anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found following query quite useful, hope it can help.

```
select      
        distinct 
        ObjJectType=
        case Obj.xType
        When 'V' then
            'VIEW'
        When 'P' then
            'PROC'
        When 'D' then
            'INDEX'
        When 'TF' then
            'TABLE FUNCTION'
        When 'FN' then
            'FUNCTION'
        When 'U' then
            'TABLE'
        When 'F' then
            'FK CONSTRAINT'
        When 'PK' then
            'PK CONSTRAINT'
        When 'TR' then
            'TRIGGER'
        When 'S' then
            'SYSTEM OBJECT'
        end ,
        Obj.name
from 
        syscomments Com inner join sysobjects Obj
  on  Com.id = Obj.id
where 
        Com.text like '%sp_name%' 
order by Obj.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a recursive query around sys.objects joined on sys.sql_modules (the definition field contains the sproc code) and build yourself a dependencies tree.

Comment: But it will be hard to decide whether a sp is inside comment or really being called if I directly query the sp code.

Comment: @lengsiqi You're right. comments handling will complicate the code.

Comment: I agree that this would be the way to go about it without some type of 3rd party tool.